# How to use in Django a register form made with html and css

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have a responsive register and login made with HTML and CSS. I don't want to use the common register form and login that Django creates when you configure it. Summarizing my problem, I know how to make the register form in Django and configure it but I don't know how to apply my template on it.  I've been reading about how to use templates on django but I still didn't figure out on how to use correctly in my case.

My register html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Manjari&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reg.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="back"></div>
<div class="registration-form">
    <header>
        <h1>Registrarse</h1>
        <p>Completa la información</p>
    </header>
    <form>
        <div class="input-section email-section"><input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu EMAIL aquí" autocomplete="off" />
            <div class="animated-button"><span class="icon-paper-plane"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span><span class="next-button email"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-section password-section folded"><input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu CONTRASEÑA aquí" />
            <div class="animated-button"><span class="icon-lock"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span><span class="next-button password"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-section repeat-password-section folded"><input class="repeat-password" type="password" placeholder="Repita la CONTRASEÑA" />
            <div class="animated-button"><span class="icon-repeat-lock"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span><span class="next-button repeat-password"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="success">
            <p>CUENTA CREADA</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="reg.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a folder called registration in your master templates folder for your project and put a template called `login.html` in it that you style as you please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to provide form action and method.And also you need to provide `name` attribute  in the input field.

For example.

```
  <form action=" " method=" " >
  <div class="input-section email-sectioni">
  <input  class="email" type="email" 
  name='your_email_field_name' 
  ........
```

Answer (score 0):

@arjun is correct. The browser will send back data using the values of the inputs with 'name' attributes, via the POST method. Your view will then be able to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0):

hi you must set LOGIN_URL='/' in django setting
and create `def login(request):` in `app.views`
then set `app.urls` on that def